# Getting periodic stats from redis

Tags: python-2.7, redis

Is there a similar command in **redis** like `stats` in **memcached** which gives the number of cumulative `get`, `set` ops separately.

e.g. in memcached I can do `stats` command and it gives:

```
STAT pid 1905
STAT uptime 87713
STAT time 1469108527
STAT version 1.4.25
STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 300.101330
STAT rusage_system 711.654138
STAT curr_connections 18
STAT total_connections 4698
STAT connection_structures 739
STAT reserved_fds 40
STAT cmd_get 75355568
STAT cmd_set 3296663
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 44369791
STAT get_misses 30985777
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 3615072874
STAT bytes_written 16173356516
STAT limit_maxbytes 3670016000
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 8
STAT conn_yields 1763246
STAT hash_power_level 17
STAT hash_bytes 1048576
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT bytes 331012787
STAT curr_items 176322
STAT total_items 3296663
STAT expired_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 0
END
```

Using this I can find out the number of get operations in the last second (by subtracting using any client library in python). I want to get the number of get and set operations per second for redis as well.

The only command that I have found is `info` and it has a *stats* section but it looks like this:

```
# Stats
slave_sync_total_commands_processed:0
slave_sync_instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_commands_processed:11562138
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_connections_received:6139
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
expire_scan_keys:0
```

And I don't see how I can use this to **find per second statistics for get and set ops**. Is there any hack or command that can do this for **redis**? Preferably something that can be done programmatically from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a hack, but rather a bona fide kosher solution - use `INFO ALL` or just `INFO CMDSTATS` for that information (which is not provided by default).